# Syntax for updating underlying instance when looping?

Tags: loops, rust, state

I have a HashMap with different hashing algorithms which implement `digest::DynDigest`, but when they are looped over and `update()`d the final hash is always the same (Sha224 `d14a...`) (you can change the file PathBuf parameter to anything and get the exact same hash every time). So the `update()` and/or `finalize()` is not updating the instance in the HashMap.

What is the correct way to loop over the different hashers so that HashMap keeps correct updated state?

```rust
use digest::{Digest, DynDigest}; // https://crates.io/crates/digest/reverse_dependencies
use sha2; // implements digest::DynDigest
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn checksum_to_hex(bytes: &[u8]) -> String {
    let mut s: String = String::new();

    for b in bytes {
        s.push_str(format!("{:02x}", b).as_str());
    }

    s
}

pub fn hash_file(
    fpath: PathBuf,
    hashers: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn DynDigest>>,
) -> io::Result<HashMap<&str, String>> {
    let f = File::open(fpath).expect("failed to open file for hashing");

    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1048576];
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);

    loop {
        let count = reader.read(&mut buffer)?;
        if count == 0 {
            break;
        }

        for (_, mut hasher) in hashers.to_owned() {
            hasher.update(&buffer[..count]);
        }
    }

    // Hash results per hasher
    let mut hashes: HashMap<&str, String> = HashMap::new();

    for (k, hasher) in hashers.to_owned() {
        let res = checksum_to_hex(hasher.finalize().to_vec().as_slice());
        hashes.insert(k, res);
    }

    Ok(hashes)
}

fn main() {
    let mut hashers: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn DynDigest>> = HashMap::new();

    hashers.insert("Sha224", Box::new(sha2::Sha224::new()));
    hashers.insert("Sha256", Box::new(sha2::Sha256::new()));
    hashers.insert("Sha512", Box::new(sha2::Sha512::new()));

    for (htype, hashres) in hash_file(PathBuf::from("/bin/ls"), hashers).expect("") {
        println!("  {} {}", htype, hashres);
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3664ea7a8403e7852d9c443c482ce23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the first `hashers.to_owned()` with `hashers.iter_mut()`:

```rust
pub fn hash_file(
    fpath: PathBuf,
    mut hashers: HashMap<&str, Box<dyn DynDigest>>,
) -> io::Result<HashMap<&str, String>> {
    let f = File::open(fpath).expect("failed to open file for hashing");

    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1048576];
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f);

    loop {
        let count = reader.read(&mut buffer)?;
        if count == 0 {
            break;
        }

        for (_, hasher) in hashers.iter_mut() {
        // or `for hasher in hashers.values_mut()`
            hasher.update(&buffer[..count]);
        }
    }

    // Hash results per hasher
    let mut hashes: HashMap<&str, String> = HashMap::new();

    for (k, hasher) in hashers {
        let res = checksum_to_hex(hasher.finalize().to_vec().as_slice());
        hashes.insert(k, res);
    }

    Ok(hashes)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b1528a65f3527ec3f368ce3a09824fe)

`.to_owned()` will clone (create an independent deep copy) the map. When you iterate over that, you're iterating through a different map than the one you eventually return.

Instead, you want to iterate over references to the elements: this is what `.iter_mut()` (or `.values_mut()` if you only need the values) will give you.

This way, you don't need the second `.to_owned()`, but you do need to mark the `hashers` argument as mutable.